# System.AccessViolationException

Tags: asp.net

InnerException: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. at System.Runtime.InteropServices.CustomMarshalers.EnumeratorViewOfEnumVariant.MoveNext()

I am getting this exception few times a day in our website. The page that create PDF file from 
the uploaded image files result in above excption. Do you have any idea what could be causing it.

Comment: You will probably need to give some more detailed information on what you are doing (such as the fragment of code where the exceoption is thrown)

Answer (score 0):

Where are the images "uploaded" to? Are you saving them to disk prior to attempting PDF, or is it done in stream? Is there any chance you are grabbing the image prior to it saving to disk? These are the things I would examine to get to the root cause.

Do you get a stack trace from the error? If so, you can isolate the line of code it is actually failing on.

If the error merely annoys you, wrap in a try ... catch and do nothing. Only kidding, btw.

Comment: User does not need to upload any images. Rather, we do have a dedicated folder for storing images of type .PDF and .EPS. And when the user clicks on button to show proof, we call upon a .ddl method to create a PDF proof which uses the images in the folder and the varaible parameters being entered by the users. It is this method which throws the exception.